# スペースで区切られた複数回答項目をダミー変数にする。

Tags: r

```
#データフレーム作成
q1 <- c("1","3","2","4","5")
q2 <- c("1 2","1 12","2 11","1 2 11 12","3 12 13")
q3 <- c("1 2 3 4 5", "2 12 13","*","11 12","1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13")
q4 <- c("5","4","3","2","*")
a <- data.frame(Q1=q1, Q2=q2,Q3=q3,Q4=q4)
```

マークカードで読み取った上記のデータフレーム。Q2とQ3のみ複数回答項目で要素がスペース区切りの文字列になっています。

結果としては"Q2_1","Q2_2....Q3_12,Q3_13のように、0 or 1のダミー変数を作成したいのですが、うまくいきません・・。

（separateとmakedummiesを使いました）

Answer (score 1):

以下、実装例を載せますが、'*' の扱いが良く分からないので、そのままにしてあります。

```
make_answer_table <- function(q, tag) {
  x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(q[q!='*'], " ")))
  vmin <- min(x); vmax <- max(x)
  setNames(data.frame(t(sapply(q, function(item) {
    if (item == '*') return(rep('*', vmax-vmin+1))
    x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(item, " ")))
    sapply(vmin:vmax, function(i){ ifelse(i %in% x, 1, 0) })
  })), row.names=1:length(q)), c(paste(tag, vmin:vmax, sep='_')))
}

q1 <- c("1","3","2","4","5")
q2 <- c("1 2","1 12","2 11","1 2 11 12","3 12 13")
q3 <- c("1 2 3 4 5", "2 12 13","*","11 12","1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13")
q4 <- c("5","4","3","2","*")

a <- cbind(
  Q1=q1,
  make_answer_table(q2, "Q2"),
  make_answer_table(q3, "Q3"),
  Q4=q4
)
```